# How to get array count of nested object in elastic-search

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

Can someone please help me to get an aggregated count of the nested object in elastic search, let say if my elastic search object mapping as :

```
{
"employe": {
"dynamic": "strict",
"properties": {
  "empId":{
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "entities": {
     "type": "nested"
      }
   }
 }
}
```

entities are the type of array with some other object. I wanted to get the count of entities of the filtered item. 
I have tried some elastic search query, but it does not work

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "empId": [12121,2121212]
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"entities_agg": {
  "sum": {
      "field": "entities",
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['entities'].values.size()"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot access nested data via doc values, you need to access the source document instead, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "empId": [
              12121,
              2121212
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "entities_agg": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "params._source.entities.size()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error
{
               "type": "script_exception",
               "reason": "runtime error",
               "script_stack": [
                  "params._source.entities.size()",
                  "                       ^---- HERE"
               ],
               "script": "params._source.entities.size()",
               "lang": "painless",
               "caused_by": {
                  "type": "null_pointer_exception",
                  "reason": null
               }
            }

Comment: That's probably because some documents don't have any `entities` field. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, then which version of ES are you using?

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.8",
    "build_date" : "2018-02-16T16:46:30.010Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  }

Comment: Can you name a sub-field that is present in all `entities`?

Comment: you are correct, I went through the detail of all the item and one of them I found item don't have entities, Thank you very much your query is working fine for me.

Comment: Ok, great, glad this helped!

Comment: One more question if my item structure is some thing like this
`{
  "entities": [
    {
      "sets": [
        {
          "text": "hello",
          "entityType": "one",
          "mention": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

then how I can get sets aggregate values now

Comment: this , here i have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270141/how-to-get-array-count-of-nested-of-nested-object-in-elastic-search, if u can help in this also